# In dependency Injection what is a dependency?

Tags: dependency-injection

I'he read a lot about this but still i am unclear about the things. We say that DI means injecting dependencies into dependent components at runtime

**Q1**

> What is a dependency ? If these are the objects created at runtime?

If yes, does that mean we are injecting values into variables by creating an object(created by framework i.e instantianting the bean via xml file with setter/constructor injection)

**Q2**

> We do the DI to do work without object intervention?

Comment: check this link http://lowcoupling.wordpress.com/2012/12/05/dependency-injection it provides an explanation with examples. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a elaborate answer to make it just simpler.

Ques1:

```
class Dependent {
  propertyA = new PropertyA();
  propertyB = new PropertyB();
}
```

Here `Dependent` is dependent to `propertyA` and `propertyB`. Above relation is an example of dependency.

If these are the objects created at runtime? Yes.

If yes....? Yes too

Ques2: Yes.

---

**Detail is included below**

Scenario 1:

```
class Dependent {
  DBConnection connection = new OracleConnection();
}
```

`Dependent` class is highly coupled. Since there is no way to change the connection unless we change the code. So if customer need MySQLConnection() we will have to change the code and give them another exe/jar.

---

Scenario 2:

```
class Dependent {
  DBConnection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection();
}
```

This is much better since, `ConnectionFactory` will be able to read some configuration and create necessary `connection`.

But still, it raises some difficulty to mock the `Dependent` class. It is hard to create mock in these scenarios. Then what?

---

Scenario 3:

```
class Dependent {
  DBConnection connection;

  setConnection(DBConnection connection) {
    this.connecttion = connection;
  }
}

class DependencyInjector {
  inject() {
    // wire them together every dependent & their dependency!
    Dependent dependent = indentiyDepenentSomeSmartWay();
    DBConnection connection = indentiyConnectionSomeSmartWay();
    dependent.setConnection(connection);
  }
}
```

Our `DependencyInjector` is a smart class, know all the necessary information! Above `Dependent` class is clean & simple. It is easy mock them for unit test, configurable using configuration.

Those object creation & coupling is detached!

Comment: `class Dependent {
  Dependent obj = new Dependent();
}` is also same ?

Comment: saying literally: if a class's objects are created at runtime by the framework, then the class is not dependent on the object. otherwise(created inside class code) it is.

Comment: @rd4code yes, something like that :). see latest edit for understanding.

Answer (score 4):

### Q1

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), all elements in DI pattern are objects. The *dependent* object specifies what it needs using interfaces. The *injector* object decides what concrete classes (instantiated objects) can satisfy the requirement and provide them to the dependent object.

So, that becomes a *yes* to the second part.

### Q2

Again from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection):

> The primary purpose of the dependency injection pattern is to allow
>   selection among multiple implementations of a given dependency
>   interface at runtime, or via configuration files, instead of at
>   compile time.

As an example consider a security service that can work different implementations of an `Encoder`. The different encoding algorithm could include SHA, MD5 and others. The security service only specifies that it needs an instance of "an encoding algorithm". The runtime DI environment then will look to find an object that is providing the interface of `Encoder` and then injects to the security service. In line with DI, the security service is also taking advantage of [Inversion of Control (IoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control); i.e. it does not *itself* decide what implementation to use but it is the DI runtime that takes that decision.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in simple words,

**For #1 :**
Dependency injection is something about satisfying the need of one object by giving it the object it requires.
Let see an example :

Generally in an enterprise application we use an architecture where in services call a DAO layer and DAO does all the database related stuff. So service need and object of DAO to call all the DAO methods.

Considering we have an entity object - **Person**.

Lets say we have a DAO - PersonDAO.

```
public interface PersonDAO {
    void addPerson(Person person);
    void updatePerson(Person person);
    void deletePerson(int personId);
}
```

and a service - PersonService.

```
public class PersonServiceImpl {
    private PersonDAO personDAO;

    public void addPerson() {
        //some code specific to service.
        //some code to create Person obj.
        personDAO.add(person);
    }
}
```

As you can see PersonService is using PersonDAO object to call its methods. PersonService depends on PersonDAO. So PersonDAO is dependency and PersonService is dependent object.

Normally in frameworks like Spring these dependencies are injected by frameworks itself. When application context is loaded all these dependency objects are created and put in Container and whenever needed they are used. The concept of Inversion of Control(IoC) is very closely related to Dependency Injection because of the way the dependency object is created.

E.g You could have created the PersonDAO object in PersonService itself as
    PersonDAO personDAO = new PersonDAOImpl();

But in case of spring you are just defining a property for PersonDAO in PersonService and providing a setter for it which is used by spring to set the dependency. Here the creation of dependency is taken care by framework instead of the class which is using it hence it is called Inversion of Control.

**For #2** : Yes. You are right.